# Walking object hierarchy in a typesafe manner

Tags: c#, algorithm, types

At work, we have a very complex data structure, TComplex:

```
public class TComplex
{
    public AType AType { get; set; }
    public BType BType { get; set; }
    public IList<CType> CTypes { get; set; }
}

public class AType
{
    public int AInteger { get; set; }
    public int BInteger { get; set; }
    public string AString { get; set; }
}

public class BType
{
    public string AString { get; set; } 
    public IList<DType> DTypes { get; set; }
}

public class CType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class DType 
{
    public string Value { get; set; }   
}
```

Which has recently modified by adding an enum ParsedValue to several node types.

```
public enum ParsedValue
{
    Parsed,
    Interpreted,
    Guessed,
    Explicit
}

public class TComplex
{
    public AType AType { get; set; }
    public BType BType { get; set; }
    public IList<CType> CTypes { get; set; }
}

public class AType
{
    public int AInteger { get; set; }
    public int BInteger { get; set; }
    public string AString { get; set; }
    public ParsedValue ParsedValue { get; set; }
}

public class BType
{
    public string AString { get; set; } 
    public IList<DType> DTypes { get; set; }
    public ParsedValue ParsedValue { get; set; }
}

public class CType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public ParsedValue ParsedValue { get; set; }
}

public class DType 
{
    public string Value { get; set; }   
}
```

**Firstly, given an object of type TComplex, how would I go about walking the hierarchy and yielding all values of ParsedValue:**

```
public static IEnumerable<ParsedValue> GetParsedValues(TComplex tComplex)
```

**Going one step further, how would I be able to set all ParsedValues in this object to a specific ParsedValue**, say ParsedValue.Explicit:

```
public static IEnumerable<Action<ParsedValue>> SetParsedValues(TComplex tComplex)
```

I have an naive implementations of GetParsedValues and SetParsedValues. However if I were to add a ParsedValue to further types in the hierarchy, then I would also need to change the implementation of GetParsedValues and SetParsedValues, which I find brittle:

```
public static IEnumerable<ParsedValue> GetParsedValues(TComplex tComplex)
{
    yield return tComplex.AType.ParsedValue;
    yield return tComplex.BType.ParsedValue;

    foreach(var cType in tComplex.CTypes)
    {
        yield return cType.ParsedValue;
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<Action<ParsedValue>> SetParsedValues(TComplex tComplex)
{
    yield return value => tComplex.AType.ParsedValue = value;
    yield return value => tComplex.BType.ParsedValue = value;

    foreach(var cType in tComplex.CTypes)
    {
        yield return value => cType.ParsedValue = value;
    }
}
```

**I've considered reflection, but is there a better way of going about this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything terribly objectionable about the way you're doing it now, really, but you could clean it up a bit if you wanted to.

One option might be to write a common base class `ParsedValueProviderBase` for all of your classes instead of an interface. Give it virtual no-op implementations of the same two methods:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<ParsedValue> GetParsedValues() 
    => Enumerable.Empty<ParsedValue>();

public virtual IEnumerable<ParsedValue> SetParsedValues(ParsedValue pv) 
    => Enumerable.Empty<ParsedValue>();
```

Subclasses can override those or not.

You could also Write an `IParsedValueThing` interface, implemented by some or all of your classes:

```
public interface IParsedValueThing {
    IEnumerable<ParsedValue> GetParsedValues();
    IEnumerable<ParsedValue> SetParsedValues(ParsedValue pv);
}
```

Have everybody implement that interface. Some of them would be just this:

```
public IEnumerable<ParsedValue> GetParsedValues() 
    => yield return ParsedValue;

public IEnumerable<ParsedValue> SetParsedValues(ParsedValue pv) 
    => yield return ParsedValue = pv;
```

Others would recurse into children, etc.

If you might be using that interface all over the place in classes other than these, that might be a good idea. You could write the interface and implement it in `ParsedValueProviderBase`.

Comment: Via reflection OP can iterate through all properties and look for the interface implementation. :-)

Comment: I like this idea. 

Can I clarify something, should I consider implement the IParsedValueThing to every type in the hierarchy, and return Enumerable.Empty<ParsedValue>() for types that don't have any ParsedValues, then fix the implementation once a ParsedValue is added?

Comment: @nvn911 That's a judgment call. If you think there's a fair chance you'll be doing that later, then you may as well lay the groundwork now. If that were the case, I would instead consider giving all of the classes a common base class which implements `IParsedValueThing` with a stub that returns `Enumerable.Empty<ParsedValue>()`. Or maybe just write a base class with a virtual for those methods, and don't bother writing a separate interface.

Answer (score 1):

To make this more generic you could have each class implement a GetParsedValues and SetParsedValues function, in your complex type you can now rely on the implementation of these functions and be sure that they return what you want to relay through.

Here I have implemented just the GetParsedValues part, the same can be applied for SetParsedValues

```
public class TComplex
{
    public AType AType { get; set; }
    public BType BType { get; set; }
    public IList<CType> CTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ParsedValue> GetParsedValues()
    {
        foreach (var parsedValue in AType.GetParsedValues())
            yield return parsedValue;
        foreach (var parsedValue in BType.GetParsedValues())
            yield return parsedValue;

        foreach (var cType in CTypes)
            foreach (var parsedValue in cType.GetParsedValues())
                yield return parsedValue;
    }
}

public class AType
{
    public int AInteger { get; set; }
    public int BInteger { get; set; }
    public string AString { get; set; }
    public ParsedValue ParsedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ParsedValue> GetParsedValues()
    {
        yield return ParsedValue;
    }
}

public class BType
{
    public string AString { get; set; } 
    public IList<DType> DTypes { get; set; }
    public ParsedValue ParsedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ParsedValue> GetParsedValues()
    {
        yield return ParsedValue;
    }
}

public class CType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public ParsedValue ParsedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ParsedValue> GetParsedValues()
    {
        yield return ParsedValue;
    }
}
```

As you can see this way you can modify your types and just edit the function of that type.